# Spark Mvc2 RC layout issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got Application.spark and home.spark views.

If layout has:

```
<span><use content="view" /></span>
```

And home has:

```
#RenderPartial("partial")
```

And partial has:

```
<div>test</div>
```

Then rendered output will be:

```
<div>test</div><span></span>
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Using this [spark version](http://github.com/subdigital/spark) with updated System.Web.Mvc assembly.

---

It seems that

```
#Html.RenderPartial(...)
```

Makes problems.

---

> ------ Test started: Assembly: Spark.Web.Mvc2.Tests.dll ------
>
> TestCase 'Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.FuturesRenderActionCanRunThroughItsProcess'
>   not executed: Futures assembly Microsoft.Web.Mvc not referenced by ASP.NET MVC 2 preview build
>
> TestCase 'Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.HtmlHelperWorksOnItsOwn'
>   failed: 
>     Expected: "[hello](/Home/world)"
>     But was:  <[hello](/Home/world)>
>       D:\Resources\CodeLibraries\Spark\subdigital-spark-b1ee7ee\src\Spark.Web.Mvc2.Tests\SparkViewFactoryTester.cs(245,0): at Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.HtmlHelperWorksOnItsOwn()
>
> TestCase 'Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.RenderPartialOrderCorrect'
>   failed: 
>     Looking for
>
> two
>
> Expected: greater than or equal to 0
>     But was:  -1
>       D:\Resources\CodeLibraries\Spark\subdigital-spark-b1ee7ee\src\Spark.Web.Mvc2.Tests\SparkViewFactoryTester.cs(155,0): at Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.ContainsInOrder(String content, String[] values)
>       D:\Resources\CodeLibraries\Spark\subdigital-spark-b1ee7ee\src\Spark.Web.Mvc2.Tests\SparkViewFactoryTester.cs(347,0): at Spark.Web.Mvc.Tests.SparkViewFactoryTester.RenderPartialOrderCorrect()
>
> 68 passed, 2 failed, 1 skipped, took 67,59 seconds (NUnit 2.4).

This test fails

```
    [Test]
    public void RenderPartialOrderCorrect()
    {

        FindViewAndRender("renderpartial-ordercorrect", "ajax");
        //mocks.VerifyAll();

        var content = output.ToString();
        ContainsInOrder(content,
                        "<p>one</p>",
                        "<p>two</p>",
                        "<p>three</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary adding [viewContextWrapper](http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4936) seems like a solution.

---

Yap... it's cool now. Including intellisense.