# is asp.net mvc 2 RC is ready for production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any risk associated by using asp.net mvc 2 on production or stick to the asp.net mvc 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (ready). Telling that from experience.

Most trouble are with 3rd party tools (i.e. - [spark hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071665/spark-mvc2-rc-layout-issue)).

Took me like 1 day to migrate completely our web app to Mvc2 RC (which ain't giant).

Asp.net Mvc has quite nice suite of unit tests and really good architecture - therefore, it's kind a stable, there aren't much breaking changes (faced only one in Mvc2 RC => viewcontext demands textwriter as last argument or something. Normally - that shouldn't be a problem and you wouldn't even notice that (not for me, cause i had mechanism that renders html as string). And there might be some issues with validation (our app is quite `read-only`)).

---

[Related blog post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/05/38476/) from our fellow member Craig. :)

Recently (current date => 2010-02-06) [Mvc2 RC2 was announced](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/05/asp-net-mvc-2-release-candidate-2-now-available.aspx).

Main changes - validation

Answer (score 1):

There will always be risks. The RC version is not officially supported by Microsoft, so if you go that way you will have to rely on the community (which btw is great). The other risk is that some features might change in the RTM and if you'd like to upgrade you may need to retest the whole application.

Other than that the ASP.NET MVC 2 RC comes with a go-live license so you could use it in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have quality processes to test *your* application then I don't see a problem with it.

I think a better question is do you want to be developing on such a recent release.

- You will find less documentation.
- You may find problems with the framework during development.
- You may find small breaking changes (only) when you update to later revisions.

In the end the source code is available if you really need to fix any problem you find in the framework. You just need to decide if you want to develop with the newer features or on a more understood and documented version.

For me, I'm moving to version 2 as soon as I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

This RC build does not have a go-live statement, so it is not supported by Microsoft. You need to wait till its final release.

Comment: What does that even mean though? What are Microsoft going to do different once it's "supported"? When you choose *any* framework, Microsoft or not, ultimately it's on you to ensure it does what you need it to do.

Comment: If a product is supported by Microsoft, you can take some advantage. But you can feel free to rely on your own.

Comment: Actually - it's even better to 'go-live' right now, because this way we can spot bugs and asp.net team might manage to fix them until RTM. Otherwise - that will take another year.

Comment: Well, it is not easy to determine whether a beta release can 'go-live'. I believe this decision for MVC 2 RC was affected by a lot of factors, so I cannot tell whether it is better or not to go live now.